# Linking in SQL and pulling based on specific criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My current query is below:

```
 SELECT [id]
       ,[reqFacility]
       ,[reqAccount]
       ,[reqAccType]
       ,[reqAccBal]
       ,[reqPatName]
       ,[reqPatMRN]
       ,[reqType]
       ,[reqBox]
       ,[reqOwner]
       ,[reqDate]
       ,[flag]
       ,[flagDate]
       ,[flagNotes]
       ,[flagUser]
       ,[reqId]
 FROM [stingRay].[dbo].[requests]
 WHERE DATEDIFF(DD,reqDate,GETDATE()) <= 3
```

When there is an instance of flag=D in the last 3 days, I would like to pull all instances in the table (also in the same time frame) having the same 'reqaccount' as any account in flag D.  Essentially, I want to link based on 'reqaccount' and only pull accounts that had a D at some point in my time frame. Any help on the matter is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Some sample data and results would probably help us to see what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT [id]
   ,[reqFacility]
   ,[reqAccount]
   ,[reqAccType]
   ,[reqAccBal]
   ,[reqPatName]
   ,[reqPatMRN]
   ,[reqType]
   ,[reqBox]
   ,[reqOwner]
   ,[reqDate]
   ,[flag]
   ,[flagDate]
   ,[flagNotes]
   ,[flagUser]
   ,[reqId]


FROM [stingRay].[dbo].[requests]
 WHERE DATEDIFF(DD,reqDate,GETDATE()) <= 3 AND reqAccount='D'
```